# SFDX SonarQube code coverage

Tags: salesforcedx, jenkins, cicd

In our org we have setup SonarQube with codescan.
The build is triggered through a Jenkins job.

Now we are struggling to get data from the coverage. eventhough we are setting the resultformat to json in
`sfdx force:apex:test:run`
My output directory is named coverage
in my sonar-project.properties I have mentioned the directory to the test-result-codecoverage.json.

```
sonar.language=Apex
sonar.projectBaseDir=.
sonar.apex.coverage.reportPath=coverage/test-result-codecoverage.json
```

But in some way the coverage value is always 0.
Does someone know how sonarqube can parse my unit test report from sfdx.

Comment: Salesforce DX does not output a standard format like Cobertura or Lcov. Have you confirmed that with your vendor that SonarQube supports SFDX's unique coverage format?

Comment: @DavidReed I have confirmed SonarQube supports sfdx format (json) out of the box. It seems that sonarqube can't access the directory I made for the test coverage